# Are there any international flights arriving in Malaysia where there is no disinsection,spraying of pesticide to kill mosquitoes?

Tags: legal, health, malaysia

Malaysia is not listed on the US Department of Transportation page regarding aircraft disinsection requirements https://www.transportation.gov/airconsumer/spray

However anecdotal evidence shows that many international flights arriving in Kuala Lumpur the cabin is sprayed. Also the British Airways page https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/travel-assistance/medical-conditions-and-pregnancy lists Malaysia under `BA Flights departing from the UK which require disinsection`.

Did anyone land anywhere in Malaysia on an international flight in the last year and remembers for sure that there was no cabin spraying, no fumigation?

Are flights from Singapore to Malaysia free from spraying?

Ideally I would like to find the source of the Malaysian regulation that require disinsection on BA flights from London, and to see does it applies to all international flight landing in Malaysia, or only some. Anecdotal evidence suggests that Air Asia sprays the cabin on most/all flights?